# .NET 7.0 preview release System.Runtime Version 7.0.0.0 not in NuGet

Tags: .net

I'm trying to export a function in C# that takes string as input parameter. Since I can only use blittable types, I had the following declaration

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedCallersOnly(EntryPoint = "eval",CharSet=CharSet.Unicode)]
        public static void eval(string ct, string parms)
        {
            ...

        }
```

This code is not compiling because CharSet in .NET 7.0 is moved from System.Runtime.InteropServices to System.Runtime version 7.0.0.0. The problem is Nuget doesn't have the assembly loaded. The highest version is 4.3.1. Anyone has any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: It does not compile because CharSet is not a valid property for [UnmanagedCallersOnly].  Very hard to guess why you think it is.

Comment: How should I define this so that I can pass string parameters? Could you point me to the right direction? Thanks! to add some context, here is the build error that I'm getting. "error CS1069: The type name 'CharSet' could not be found in the namespace 'System.Runtime.InteropServices'. This type has been forwarded to assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' Consider adding a reference to that assembly. [/Users/yangsong/hack/MyFristWasiApp/MyFristWasiApp.csproj]"